# How to make Blazor project work in subfolder?

Tags: blazor

We created an app with blazor. It was working on localhost:5000

With nginx we make it work on ip address like this

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    include proxy.conf;
}
```

Now we want to have many apps on the same ip address in subfolders so we can access them like http://ipaddress/app1/, http://ipadress/app2

We make changes in nginx

```
location /app1 {
               proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000/;
               include proxy.conf;
        }

location /app2 {
             proxy_pass     http://localhost:5001/;
             include proxy.conf;
        }
```

In order to make it properly work with assets we set in Startup.cs file in Configure method

```
app.UsePathBase("/app1/");
```

Everything works fine on developer mashine and in browser in head tag we have

```
<base href="/app1/">
```

But when we publish and put code on the server we get

```
<base href="/">
```

and app not working how it should be.

Comment: How do you publish ?

Comment: Visual studio has function to publish projects.

Comment: I publish with configurations: Release, netcoreapp3.1, Self-Contained, linux-arm, produce single file, delete all existing files prior to publish.